# Publish npm package project directly to github repository

Tags: github, npm

**Please note, i'm new to npm package manager.**

I've created a simple bootstrap 4 sass+gulp starter project using npm package commands and scripts. Now i want to publish this project in a new github repository. I understand i can manually create a github repo, copy my project files and commit.

However, im curious
 - to learn the better workflow / approach.
 - Is there any npm tool /workflow for any github integration, for publishing?
 - Is that the better approach first to create the github repository for any such project? clone then do other stuffs?

*This time its only the artifacts. But, latter it might be a project with source where the project dependent artifacts will hold in npm package manager. However, i also noticed that lots of artifacts available in npm packages also has a github repo.*

Comment: you are wanting to publish the artifacts to the github repo, or the original source you built using npm to github? please update your question with this info. It doesn't really make much sense to upload the artifact to github, as github is usually used to host source code that is subsequently built using npm on a build machine... npm repo is what is used to host artifacts built using npm...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this time its only the artifacts. But, latter it might be a project with source where the project dependent artifacts will hold in npm package manager. However, i also noticed that lots of artifacts available in npm packages also has a github repo.

Comment: have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-git-publish ? also, your question appears to be asking for a recommended library or something, which is apparently very bad according to stackoverflow rules... in any case, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

### Git Commit

```
git add -A . && git commit -a -m 'gh-pages update'
```

### Publish to Git

```
git push origin gh-pages --force && git checkout master
```

Make sure you're inside the folder of the package you need to publish onto Github for all the commands to work.

### Publish to NPM

(Just in case)

Make sure you have name and package entries in your `package.json` file, then:
`npm adduser`
Verify that your user is set properly by running `npm config ls` finally `npm publish` should do the trick